# How To Create An Anti-Aliased Transparent Form In VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, transparency

I have a problem with making forms with transparent background. when I set a color for the `BackColor` and assign that color to the `TransparencyKey` property, that back ground will be transparent but my edges will be sharp and the back color around the pictures will not hide and looks like a sharp ugly border. what should I do? How can I fix this?

Comment: Google "windows forms per pixel alpha transparency".  You cannot use controls like TextBox on your form when you do that, they won't be visible.

Comment: What? I sat i want no black color on the form. Where the text box came from?